# When Ubuntu starts, networking is disabled

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I notice that when my Ubuntu 16 laptop reboots, at the start up screen my WiFi network will temporarily connect, but after a few moments it disconnects.

I have edited my `/etc/rc.local` to have `service network-manager restart` in it, and although I think it works temporarily, the network enevitably goes down.

So this is weird. It *does* connect, but then it disconnects and I have to manually log into the laptop for the connection to re-establish.

Just in case, here is my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Update 1: 
Here is what it says in my `systemctl status NetworkManager.service` status:

`Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)`

But when I do run this command, I get the following results:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable NeworkManager.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what does `systemctl status NetworkManager.service` show? In that output, you need to make sure it says "enabled" in the `Loaded` row. If it is not, you need to enable it by running `sudo systemctl enable NeworkManager.service`

Comment: @xR34P3Rx - I updated my question with answers

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my behalf, i put Nework instead of Network. Either way, looks like that service is in fact running. You may want to check the logs on `/var/log/syslog` right after it disconnects and see if it logged anything. You can also run `sudo journalctl -xe` and see if it logged any network issues.